# Отправка одной кнопкой несколько форм по ajax

Tags: jquery, ajax

Имеется **n** форм на странице, пытаюсь отправить последовательно содержимое всех форм по ajax на страницу save.php, но передаются пустые строки. Подскажите что не так?

````
```
<form enctype="multipart/form-data" method="POST" id="form1">
    <input id="user_id1" name="user_id" value="1" class="d-none">
    <input id="nomer1" name="nomer">
    <input id="date11" name="date1" type="date">
    <input id="date21" name="date2" type="date">
</form>
...
<form enctype="multipart/form-data" method="POST" id="form8">
    <input id="user_id8" name="user_id" value="8" class="d-none">
    <input id="nomer8" name="nomer">
    <input id="date18" name="date1" type="date">
    <input id="date28" name="date2" type="date">
</form>

<button id="save" type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Сохранить</button>

<script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $("#save").click(function(){
            form1 = $("#form1");
            $.ajax({
                url: "save.php",
                method: "POST",
                contentType:false,
                processData:false,
                //data: new FormData($("#form1")),
                data: form1.serialize(),
                success: function(msg){
                    alert(msg);
                }
            });
            ...
            form8 = $("#form8");
            $.ajax({
                url: "save.php",
                method: "POST",
                contentType:false,
                processData:false,
                //data: new FormData($("#form8")),
                data: form.serialize(),
                success: function(msg){
                    alert(msg);
                }
            });
        }); 
    });
</script>
```
````

Comment: это разные формы `form8 = $("#form8"); form.serialize(),` А так - сделали  бы цикл по всем формам, чтоб не множить текст

Comment: "но передаются пустые строки" - куда?

Comment: @splash58 Я понимаю, но как мне тут `data: new FormData($("#form8")),` или тут `data: form.serialize(),` обратиться к форме?

Comment: если `form8 = $("#form8")`, то  итут form8 `form8.serialize()`

Comment: @splash58 я отпечатался там, исправил, но всё равно

Comment: @igor из формы в переменную data

Comment: ну а что в массиве $POST приходит?

Comment: @splash58 пустые строки

Comment: @splash58 `echo print_r($_POST);` выдаёт `Array ( ) 1`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Уберите эти две строки

```
            contentType:false,
            processData:false,
```

В результате этих инструкций вы просто ничего не  передаете на сервер

> processData (default: true) Type: Boolean By default, data passed in
> to the data option as an object (technically, anything other than a
> string) will be processed and transformed into a query string, fitting
> to the default content-type "application/x-www-form-urlencoded". If
> you want to send a DOMDocument, or other non-processed data, set this
> option to false.

> contentType (default: 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded;
> charset=UTF-8') Type: Boolean or String When sending data to the
> server, use this content type. Default is
> "application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8", which is fine for
> most cases. If you explicitly pass in a content-type to $.ajax(), then
> it is always sent to the server (even if no data is sent). As of
> jQuery 1.6 you can pass false to tell jQuery to not set any content
> type header. Note: The W3C XMLHttpRequest specification dictates that
> the charset is always UTF-8; specifying another charset will not force
> the browser to change the encoding. Note: For cross-domain requests,
> setting the content type to anything other than
> application/x-www-form-urlencoded, multipart/form-data, or text/plain
> will trigger the browser to send a preflight OPTIONS request to the
> server.

Comment: Да храни вас господь, убрал `contentType:false` и отправилось! Просто при отправке одной формы через `data: new FormData($("#form1")),` работало только с `contentType:false`

Comment: Понял свою ошибку, я выключил преобразование объекта в строку и попытался передать объект. Ещё раз благодарю!